# Execute SP using Entity Framework and .net Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a web api project using .net core and entity framework.
This uses a stored procedure which returns back most of the properties of a database table defined by entity framework.

The entity framwrok does not bring back all the columns of the table. And I get an error when I call the api complaining it cannot find the missing columns when I execute the stored procedure using ,

```
_context.Set<TableFromSql>().FromSql("execute dbo.spr_GetValue").ToList();
```

I created another model class which defines the properties brought back from the SP( called NewClass).

```
_context.Set<NewClass>().FromSql("execute dbo.spr_GetValue").ToList();
```

This works, but just wanted to check if there is a convention that the SP should only return the model classes from the database.

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). It states under limitations: _The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity or query type_

Comment: So does that mean I should not add my own model class and change the SP to return all the properties of the entity. So what about really complicated sql SP which does not need the entire column to return(may be uses joins between tables in database)?

Comment: No, its not exactly what I meant. EF Core (since 2.1) has two types of models: Entities (which map to tables in the Database) and "query types" (as Tau Zhou mentioned in his answer). Query types do not map to database tables. From Your queries it wasn't very clear if `TableFromSql` is a model or not. But anyways, the limitation of above applies to both: Entities and Query types. If `TableFromSql` is an entity and the procedure only returns a subset of the properties, you should use query types instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The SQL query must return data for all properties of the entity or query type

For this limitation, it is caused when mapping the sql query result to `Model`. It loop through the properties in model and try to retrive the values from query result. If the model properties are not exist in `query result`, it will throw error.

If you want to return required columns instead of all columns, one options is to define the returned model by `Query`.

For your demo code, you may define this in `OnModelCreating`.

```
builder.Query<TableFromSql>();
```

**Note**, for this way, you need to make sure all properties in `TableFromSql` exist in `execute dbo.spr_GetValue`.

For another way, you may implement your own `FromSql` which will add condition to check whether the properties are exist in query result.

```
    public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static List<T> RawSqlQuery<T>(this DbContext context,string query)
    {
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                var entities = new List<T>();

                return DataReaderMapToList<T>(result);
            }
        }
    }
    public static List<T> DataReaderMapToList<T>(IDataReader dr)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        T obj = default(T);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (ColumnExists(dr, prop.Name))
                {
                    if (!object.Equals(dr[prop.Name], DBNull.Value))
                    {

                        prop.SetValue(obj, dr[prop.Name], null);
                    }
                }
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static bool ColumnExists(IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {

        return reader.GetSchemaTable()
                     .Rows
                     .OfType<DataRow>()
                     .Any(row => row["ColumnName"].ToString() == columnName);
    }
}
```

Use above code like :

```
        var result = _context.RawSqlQuery<ToDoItemVM>("execute [dbo].[get_TodoItem]");
```

Comment: I created a new model class called "NewClass.cs" as mentioned above and added it to the context.cs like 
modelBuilder.Entity<NewClass>(entity => { entity.HasKey(e => e.LocationId); }); this works fine. But I just wanted to know if this was wrong way to do it?

Comment: @liroforum this is right and current recommend way to return custom columns from sp. `builder.Query` is used to return custom models.

Comment: So I have added the new class to the modelBuilder like modelBuilder.Query<NewClass>(); and used it in the controller like _context.Query<NewClass>().FromSql("execute dbo.spr_GetValue").ToList(); . Is this correct or did you mean something else? Is it possible to call the sql SP from the context.cs as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types ?

Comment: Thanks Tao, this helped.